# Hair particle system, hair particles go down throgh the scalp

Tags: particles, hair

I have looked at other similar topics on this and other forums, but have not found a solution that suits me.

In particle mode, everything looks normal, but in object mode, you can see that a lot of hair goes straight down, and a bald spot forms on the top of the head. In the particle settings set only the vertex group and children to interpolated.

Adding a collision to a character doesn't work either. All modifiers are applied. Transforms were applied.

I may have missed something due to inexperience, and I would be grateful if you could help me and suggest a solution.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable **B-Spline** for the particle system and increase the **Steps**.

Steps for both Render and the Viewport are a power of 2, meaning the hair will have `2^n` segments with `n` steps. If you increase steps by 2, the number of segments multiplies by 4.

[image: hair splines]